# Battleship game placement of boats error

Tags: java

Ok i am inches away from finishing this game, but I am getting one error with the code:

```
cshi.addActionListener(new VesselFunction());
```

it says VesselFunction cant be resolved to a type, but I have no clue why. If i delete the code, it compiles and the program runs but it only lets me place one boat, so I clearly need the code to work so it can call on other methods to place the remaining 4 boats. What should I do?

Comment: Do you even have a VesselFunction class? Are you sure? Have you checked spelling, etc?

Comment: This is an Eclipse error, right? Because Java does not say such things...

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels: You were right, that I made too many assumptions. It was a guess shot. I deleted my answer.

Comment: @pvblivs: When I guess, I usually try to do so in the comments section rather than answer section.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Will keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that it doesn't find the `VesselFunction` class. Check your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If the VesselFunction class lives in a different package than that of the current source file, you will need to use an `import` statement to reference it by its Simple name (VesselFunction), as opposed to its Fully-Qualified class name (com.something.somethingelse.VesselFunction).

You also need to make sure the VesselFunction.class file exists in the proper directory inside the classpath you are using.